# Include Go dependencies in Docker container using mono repo

Tags: docker, go, golang-migrate

I have a mono repo with the structure.

```
mono-repo
- serviceA
 - main.go
 - Dockerfile
-serviceB
 - main.go
 - Dockerfile
go.mod
go.sum
```

The Dockerfile in serviceA contains the following code.

```
FROM golang

ENV GO111MODULE=on

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/serviceA"]
```

I want to build the Docker image and include the dependencies from the root of my mono-repo inside the container, I am currently receiving an error saying it can't find any of the dependency packages when I run

> docker build -t serviceA .

Unless I place a go.mod inside serviceA I can't see a nice way of achieving what I want. By placing a go.mod inside the service it feels like I'm losing the advantage of services sharing dependencies within the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By placing a go.mod inside the service it feels like I'm losing the advantage of services sharing dependencies within the repo.

Yet, this is an approach seen [here](https://dev.to/plutov/docker-and-go-modules-3kkn) or [there](https://container-solutions.com/faster-builds-in-docker-with-go-1-11/), where `COPY go.mod .` (and `COPY go.sum .`) is followed by `RUN go mod download`.

```
#This is the ‘magic’ step that will download all the dependencies that are specified in 
# the go.mod and go.sum file.
# Because of how the layer caching system works in Docker, the  go mod download 
# command will _ only_ be re-run when the go.mod or go.sum file change 
# (or when we add another docker instruction this line)
RUN go mod download
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Local dependencies (serviceB) are not fetched via `go mod download`

Comment: @RicardoTomasi What `go` command would then download those local dependencies? `go get` (with Go 1.16+)?